# Probability of success for multiple, parallel avenues to desired outcome

Tags: probability, reliability

Help please.
I am trying to establish the overall probability that at least one of many parallel avenues of pursuit will lead to a successful, desired outcome. Please allow me to explain.

A study has been done using regression analysis. I am searching files and history for that study now, but in essence, it is set up as described below.

The study "gauges" how various forms of rehabilitation and other supports contribute to the successful re-employment of a disabled person. The study gives various probabilities (with confidence intervals) for each of the rehabilitative tools exercised. In general, it compares these various probabilities across three groups of people, namely, those who are sensory impaired, those who are physically impaired and those who are mentally impaired.

All these probabilities are usually above unity as they are compared to a reference group of European/white, male in age range of 34 to 54 with a college education.

While I don't have the study currently handy to use the actual numbers just as this moment, I can at least explain the concept of my statistical pursuit using some hypothetical probabilities for example.

Suppose that we use the column for those stricken with a mental disability, and the probability that one in that category will become successfully employed by job retraining and education with a probability of 1.40 above the reference group. Also suppose that the independent probability for that same person is 1.21 if counseling services are provided. Continuing with say just one more tool of offering on-the-job assistive technologies that have a probability of say 1.35.

If one applies all three of these treatment tools to this individual's situation, what is the composite, overall probability of the desired outcome, namely re-employment?
Is it simply the highest probability of the three applied treatments (1.40), or are there some "synergistic" improvements?

I understand the various reliability equations for probability for various systems with series (dependent forms with multiplicative effects, p1 * p2 * p3...) and parallel, redundant systems [with p1 + p2(1-p1)...], but these apply to probabilities of less than unity.

Since the probability of 1.40 means that the individual is forty percent more likely than the reference group to acquire employment, wouldn't applying all three methods result in 0.40 + 0.21(1-0.40) + 0.35(1-.21(1-0.40)) be the likelihood?

Answer (score 0):

After finding and researching the study/analysis methods involved further, I discovered these aren't probabilities at all, even though discussions in the study refer to them as such. These are actually odds ratios computed from a reference group using logistic regression techniques. From what I understand, though mathematically one can determine the probability of the outcome at the intersection of the various possible treatments applied, it is easier to work with the logs of these (called logit), using various matrix algebraic techniques (dot-products and cross-products as needed) to ultimately derive the intersecting probability sought after. I am reviewing those formulae and techniques now with the specific data presented in the study. Please disregard this problem in light of this new information, using odds ratios rather than probabilities. This is why these numbers exceed the normal range of probability from zero to one.